# How to change the JDK/JRE version in soapUI on windows machine?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soapui

I want my soapUI to point jdk/jre 1.6 in windows machine. So how to do that?

Comment: what version of soapui are you using?

Comment: I'm using soapUI 5.2.1

Comment: Why do you want to use jdk 6? That is not supported by SoapUI. Please refer [official note](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Announcement-Java-7-required-for-SoapUI-Open-Source-5-2-coming/m-p/129479#U129479)

Comment: okay, thanks. I have deployed all my application using JDK 6. So when I'm trying to create war from SoapUI, that war file is not supported by the application. Is there any lower version of SoapUI which supports JAVA6?